# Basic URL rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htaccess to rewrite a URL that includes a querystring.

Basically I'm trying to change this URL:
http://www.myurl.com/index.php?page=case

..to this..

http://www.myurl.com/case

my code looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^case/?$   index.php?page=case  [NC]
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?page=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

It will change `http://www.myurl.com/index.php?page=case` to `http://www.myurl.com/case`